Don't works Inline Button in scheduled message
im writing telegram bot on aiogram and have some function:
async def some_func():
    err = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='open_1', callback_data='number_1')
    btn_2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='open_2', callback_data='number_2')
    err.add(btn_1, btn_2)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='choose:', reply_markup=err)

also i have callback_handler:
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith=['number_'])
async def number(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery)
    variant = callback_query.data.split("_")
    if variant[1] == 1:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='number_1'
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='number_2'

also some_func() will be execute by scheduler:
async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every().day.at("20:39").do(some_func)
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def on_startup(_):
    await asyncio.create_task(scheduler())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)

why inlinebuttons dont works? why callback_handler dont catch pressing button?

if you are using the new aiogram version (ex. 3.8), in decorator of callback query you should use @dp.callback_query, not @dp.callback_query_handler. You can read aiogram 3.8 documentation here.
This is a simple example that is given in the documentation, its main error:
@router.callback_query()
async def callback_query_handler(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery) -> Any: pass

Here is code, I changed delay before sending a message to a simpler one. Fixed syntax errors.
import asyncio
import datetime
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery

bot = Bot(token='')
dp = Dispatcher()
CHAT_ID = 0000000001

async def some_func():
    await wait('20:39')
    err = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    err.button(text='open_1', callback_data='number_1')
    err.button(text='open_2', callback_data='number_2')
    # err.adjust(2) - Optional
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='choose:', reply_markup=err.as_markup())


@dp.callback_query(F.data.startswith('number_'))
async def number(callback_query: CallbackQuery):
    await callback_query.answer('')  # button response
    variant = callback_query.data.split("_")
    if variant[1] == 1:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='number_1')
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='number_2')


async def main():
    await some_func()
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


async def wait(time_wait):
    time = ''
    while time != time_wait:
        time = str(datetime.datetime.now())[11:16]
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        # await asyncio.sleep(60) - You can use 60 sec delay.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

I advise you to use InlineKeyboardBuilder() instead of InlineKeyboardButton.
As you can see, parameter text_startswith of decorator callback_query is not supported now. Please, read aiogram documentation, if your aiogram version below 3.8, update aiogram:
pip install --upgrade aiogram

